# batch executing file's in a zip file

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

I have a zip file with 5 .reg files in it they are called:

```
HKLM.reg
HKCU.reg
HKCR.reg
HKU.reg
HKCC.reg
```

How do I make a batch file execute them when they are in the zip file.
Can any one help?

**EDIT:** I do have 7-zip command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to unzip them (temporarily) using 7-zip, and, use [Regedit command line](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/82821) to update the registry. Create a batch file that uses 7-zip command line to unzip the contents of your zip file. That's the first step. Then, in the same batch file, use the regedit command line switches to run the Regedit program with the names of the .reg files you just unzipped.

Comment: Could you add some more detail.

Comment: Create a batch file that uses 7-zip command line to unzip the contents of your zip file.  That's the first step.  Then, in the same batch file, use the regedit command line switches to run the Regedit program with the names of the .reg files you just unzipped.